# etymology of the phrase "at all"

Tags: etymology, history

I couldn't get much on this phrase. It is a weird one I know but I just can't stand not knowing it. How did the current use of "at all" come into being?

Take a look at [*this*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=at+all):

> "in any way," mid-14c., originally used only affirmatively (as in I Sam. XX:6 in KJV: "If thy father at all misse me"); now it is overwhelmingly used only in the negative or in interrogatory expressions, or in literary attempts at Irish dialect.

Can this be trusted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may trust this. It is drawn from [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/oed01arch#page/226/mode/2up), 9.b., where you may see representative citations going back to ‘*c* 1350’.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Look at the very last line of the first column on the left, (**9.**) **b. At all**, *et. seq.*

Answer (score 0):

If you are thinking of the same use of "...at all" as I am, it does not match what's in the Etymology.com listing...at all.

It seems to be a popular expression in current US TV shows with my first recollection coming from an episode of "The Nanny", a US TV Sitcom 1993-1999):

> **Fran (to C.C.): "Question. When they shot Bambi's mother, did you find that a sad moment... *at all*?"**

And to *hear* it, go to 5:56 of this YouTube video of the episode (Season 1, episode 7 "Imaginary Friends"): http://youtu.be/8jHgbimgFBA

Comment: In what way does *in any way* not suit your quotation?

Comment: @StoneyB, it fits but IMO falls short of the (comedic? dramatic?) impact of "...at all" versus "in any way".

Comment: Professional pride obliges me to protest that what a first-rate writer and a first-rate actor can *make* of an ordinary phrase can hardly be said to constitute "current use"! :)

Comment: @StoneyB, by "current use" I mean that others have adapted the peculiar affected way of saying ***"...at all"***, again, I believe for comedic effect, though the *meaning* is undisputedly *in any way*.  It's not the meaning that makes it "a thing", it's the particular phrase spoken a particular way.